Semimetrizability of pointed irrational/rational extensions of reals
This is intended to be a self-answering question, which is allowed on StackExchange sites (see here).
This question is inspired by this MSE post by @PiotrP, in which they outlined a possible proof that the pointed rational extension of reals topology is semimetrizable and speculated that the pointed irrational extension of reals topology might be, in contrast, non-semimetrizable. The current question asks whether these are indeed the case.
To begin, we recall the definition of semimetrizability:
Definition: A topological space $X$ is called semimetrizable if there exists a function $d:X^2\to[0,\infty)$ which is reflexive, i.e., $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$; and symmetric, i.e., $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ for all $x,y\in X$; and, for any $x\in X$, $B_d(x,\epsilon)=\{y\in X:d(x,y)<\epsilon\}$ for all $\epsilon>0$ form a local neighborhood basis at $x$. We remark that $B_d(x,\epsilon)$ needs not be open in general. Such a function $d$ is called a semimetric for $X$.
We also recall the construction of pointed irrational/rational extension topologies. In fact, we shall consider the following more general construction:
Definition: Let $X$ be a topological space and $D\subset X$. Then the pointed $D$-extension topology on $X$ is the space $X_D$ with the same underlying set as $X$, and, for each $x\in X_D$, a local basis of topology at $x$ is given by $\{x\}\cup(D\cap U)$ where $U$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$.
The pointed irrational extension of reals is when $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $D=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, while the pointed rational extension of reals is when $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $D=\mathbb{Q}$.

Is the pointed irrational/rational extension of reals semimetrizable?

More generally, we may ask the following question:

Let $X$ be a semimetrizable space and $D\subset X$ be a co-dense subset. When is $X_D$ semimetrizable?


Mind saying what co-dense is?

@PatrickR The complement is dense.

We will directly answer the second question via the following result:
Theorem: Let $X$ be a semimetrizable space and $D\subset X$ be a co-dense subset. Then $X_D$ is semimetrizable iff $D$ is $F_\sigma$ in $X$.
Note that, as $\mathbb{Q}$ is $F_\sigma$ in $\mathbb{R}$, this implies the pointed rational extension of reals is semimetrizable, retrieving @PiotrP's result in their post. But, as $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is not $F_\sigma$ in $\mathbb{R}$, the pointed irrational extension of reals is not semimetrizable.
Proof of Theorem: Assume $D\subset X$ is $F_\sigma$, i.e., we may write $D=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n$ where $D_n$ are closed subsets of $X$. Let $d'$ be a semimetric for $X$. We shall define a semimetric $d$ for $X_D$ as follows (the definition of this semimetric is inspired by the semimetric defined in @PiotrP's post):

$d(x,x)=0$, for all $x\in X$;
$d(x,y)=1$, if $x,y\notin D$ and $x\neq y$;
$d(x,y)=d(y,x)=\max\{\frac{1}{n},d'(x,y)\}$, if $x\notin D$, $y\in D$, $\min\{m:y\in D_m\}=n$;
$d(x,y)=d'(x,y)$, if $x,y\in D$.

It is easy to check $d$ is reflexive and symmetric, so we only need to show $B_d(x,\epsilon)$ form a neighborhood basis at $x$. Assume first $x\in D$ and let $n=\min\{m:x\in D_m\}$. Let $V$ be an open neighborhood of $x$ in $X_D$. Then there exists $U$, open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$, s.t. $D\cap U\subset V$. Since $U$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$, there exists $\epsilon'>0$ s.t. $B_{d'}(x,\epsilon')\subset U$. Let $\epsilon=\min\{\epsilon',\frac{1}{n}\}$. Then by definition of $d$, we see that,
$$B_d(x,\epsilon)=D\cap B_{d'}(x,\epsilon)\subset D\cap B_{d'}(x,\epsilon')\subset D\cap U\subset V$$
Thus, it now suffices to show that $B_d(x,\epsilon')$ has $x$ in its $X_D$-interior for all $\epsilon'>0$. Again, let $\epsilon=\min\{\epsilon',\frac{1}{n}\}$, so we again have $B_d(x,\epsilon)=D\cap B_{d'}(x,\epsilon)$. As $d'$ is a semimetric for $X$, there exists $U$, open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$, s.t. $U\subset B_{d'}(x,\epsilon)$. But then,
$$D\cap U \subset D\cap B_{d'}(x,\epsilon)=B_d(x,\epsilon)\subset B_d(x,\epsilon')$$
and $D\cap U$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $X_D$.
Let us now consider the case where $x\notin D$. Let $V$ be an open neighborhood of $x$ in $X_D$. Then there exists $U$, open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$, s.t. $\{x\}\cup(D\cap U)\subset V$. Again, since $U$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$, there exists $\epsilon'>0$ s.t. $B_{d'}(x,\epsilon')\subset U$. Let $\epsilon=\min\{\epsilon',1\}$. Let $n=\min\{m:\frac{1}{m}<\epsilon\}$. Then by definition of $d$, we see that,
$$\begin{split}
B_d(x,\epsilon)&=\{x\}\cup\left[(B_{d'}(x,\epsilon)\cap D)\setminus\left(\bigcup_{m=1}^{n-1}D_m\right)\right]\\
&\subset\{x\}\cup(B_{d'}(x,\epsilon')\cap D)\\
&\subset\{x\}\cup(U\cap D)\\
&\subset V
\end{split}$$
Thus, it now suffices to show that $B_d(x,\epsilon')$ has $x$ in its $X_D$-interior for all $\epsilon'>0$. Again, let $\epsilon=\min\{\epsilon',1\}$. As $d'$ is a semimetric for $X$, there exists $U$, open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$, s.t. $U\subset B_{d'}(x,\epsilon)$. But then,
$$\begin{split}
\{x\}\cup\left[\left(U\setminus\left(\bigcup_{m=1}^{n-1}D_m\right)\right)\cap D\right]&=\{x\}\cup\left[(U\cap D)\setminus\left(\bigcup_{m=1}^{n-1}D_m\right)\right]\\
&\subset\{x\}\cup\left[(B_{d'}(x,\epsilon)\cap D)\setminus\left(\bigcup_{m=1}^{n-1}D_m\right)\right]\\
&=B_d(x,\epsilon)\\
&\subset B_d(x,\epsilon')
\end{split}$$
Since $D_m$ are all closed in $X$, $U\setminus\left(\bigcup_{m=1}^{n-1}D_m\right)$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$. Thus, $\{x\}\cup\left[\left(U\setminus\left(\bigcup_{m=1}^{n-1}D_m\right)\right)\cap D\right]$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $X_D$.
We now prove the converse, i.e., we now assume $X_D$ is semimetrizable and we need to show $D\subset X$ is $F_\sigma$. Let $d$ be a semimetric for $X_D$. We define the following function:
$$f:X\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=\inf\{d(x,y):y\in X\setminus D\}$$
Clearly, $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in X\setminus D$. When $x\in D$, $D$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $X_D$, so there exists $\epsilon>0$ s.t. $B_d(x,\epsilon)\subset D$. But then $d(x,y)\geq\epsilon$ for all $y\notin D$, so $f(x)\geq\epsilon>0$. Since $X\setminus D$ is dense in $X$, $f$ is discontinuous at any $x\in D$.
On the other hand, $f$ is continuous at any $x\in X\setminus D$. To see this, let $\epsilon>0$. Then $B_d(x,\epsilon)$ has $x$ in its $X_D$-interior, so there exists $U$, open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$, s.t. $\{x\}\cup(D\cap U)\subset B_d(x,\epsilon)$. In particular, for any $y\in D\cap U$, we have $f(y)\leq d(x,y)<\epsilon$. When $y\in U\setminus D$, we have $f(y)=0$. Either way, when $y\in U$, we have $f(y)<\epsilon$, so $f$ is continuous at $x$.
Recall that, for a topological space $X$ and a real-valued function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$, its set of continuity is $G_\delta$ in $X$. (For completeness, here is a sketch of the proof: Let $A_n=\bigcup\{U\subset X:U\text{ open},|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{1}{n}\text{ for all }x,y\in U\}$. Then $A_n$ is open for all $n$ and the set of continuity is exactly $\bigcap_n A_n$.) Thus, $X\setminus D\subset X$ is $G_\delta$, so $D\subset X$ is $F_\sigma$. $\square$
Remark: Note that the backwards direction never used the condition that $D\subset X$ is co-dense, i.e., as long as $X$ is semimetrizable and $D\subset X$ is $F_\sigma$, then $X_D$ is semimetrizable. On the other hand, the forward direction never used the condition that $X$ is semimetrizable, i.e., as long as $D\subset X$ is co-dense and $X_D$ is semimetrizable, then $D\subset X$ is $F_\sigma$.

Nice proof (+1), especially the forward direction.  Minor typo at the end of the first half of the first part: $B_d(x,\epsilon)\subset B_{d'}(x,\epsilon')$

@PatrickR Thanks! I’m not sure where is the typo you referred to, though? Did you mean the formula $D\cap U \subset D\cap B_{d'}(x,\epsilon)=B_d(x,\epsilon)\subset B_d(x,\epsilon')$? That line is correct as is. It should be $B_d(x,\epsilon)\subset B_d(x,\epsilon')$ instead of $B_d(x,\epsilon)\subset B_{d’}(x,\epsilon')$ at the end.

My bad.  There was indeed no typo.
